# Getting All the record of particular month - Building SQL Query

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need some help to build SQL Query. I have table having data like:

```
ID  Date        Name
1   1/1/2009    a
2   1/2/2009    b
3   1/3/2009    c
```

I need to get result something like...

```
1    1/1/2009    a
2   1/2/2009    b
3   1/3/2009    c
4   1/4/2009    Null
5   1/5/2009    Null
6   1/6/2009    Null
7   1/7/2009    Null
8   1/8/2009    Null
............................
............................
............................
30  1/30/2009   Null
31  1/31/2009   Null
```

I want query something like..

```
Select * from tbl **where month(Date)=1 AND year(Date)=2010**
```

Above is not completed query.

I need to get all the record of particular month, even if some date missing..

I guess there must be equi Join in the query, I am trying to build this query using Equi join

Thanks

Comment: Ok, I think I know what you're after here now.

You want all possible dates in a month, even if they don't exist in your table?

Comment: see below.  Don't have access to SQL 2005 right now, but will in about 30 minutes.  If there is anything wrong with that query, let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**BIG EDIT**

Now understand the OPs question.

Use a common table expression and a left join to get this effect.

```
DECLARE @FirstDay DATETIME;

-- Set start time
SELECT @FirstDay = '2009-01-01';

WITH Days AS 
(
  SELECT @FirstDay as CalendarDay
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, CalendarDay) as CalendarDay
  FROM Days
  WHERE DATEADD(d, 1, CalendarDay) < DATEADD(m, 1, @FirstDay)
)
SELECT DATEPART(d,d.CalendarDay), **t.date should be (d.CalendarDay)**, t.Name  FROM Days d
LEFT JOIN tbl t
ON
  d.CalendarDay = t.Date
ORDER BY 
  d.CalendarDay;
```

**Left this original answer at bottom**

You need **DATEPART**, sir.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE DATEPART(m,Date) = 1
```

If you want to choose month and year, then you can use DATEPART twice or go for a range.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE DATEPART(m,Date) = 1 AND DATEPART(yyyy,Date) = 2009
```

Range :-

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Date >= '2009-01-01' AND Date < '2009-02-01'
```

See this link for more info on DATEPART.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Comment: There is no difference b/w your query and my query, both will return same.... DATEPART(m,Date) = 1 = month(Date)=1

Comment: ORDER BY  
  t.CalendarDay; Invalid column name 'CalendarDay'.

Comment: @Paul; Thanks it works after 1 change. I did the change in your answer. thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use less or equal to.

Like so:

```
select * from tbl where date > '2009-01-01' and date < '2009-02-01'
```

However, it is unclear if you want month 1 from all years?

You can check more examples and functions on "[Date and Time Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258863(SQL.80).aspx)" from MSDN

Comment: I have wrote better query, both will return same, but I need to get all the record of that month

Comment: Look in the documentation i provided, your answer is there and in the answers you've got here.

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary table containing all days of that certain month,

Do left outer join between that table and your data table on tempTable.month = #month.

now you have a big table with all days of the desired month and all the records matching the proper dates + empty records for those dates who have no data.

i hope that's what you want.